# How run modal and arithmetic operator for several buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue with adding addition buttons for a modal and arithmetic operator control. Please see my code for detail. 
It works when I have only one button. Once I added the second button, the arithmetic operator control is not working right. 
Is there a better way to run several buttons with only one arithmetic operator control ?

Below are the link:

```js
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
var btn2 = document.getElementById('b2');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";}
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
//Arithematic Operator Control
// For Button 1
var target_value = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
function checkValue(){
  var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal1');
  var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById('b1');
  var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
  var targetValue = parseInt(target_value.value);
  
  if (value < targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else if (value >= targetValue){
    buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit.innerText = '1';
  }
  modal.style.display = "none" ;
  return false;
}
// For Button 2
var target_value = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
function checkValue(){
  var inputvalue2 = document.getElementById('modal1');
  var buttonsubmit2 = document.getElementById('b2');
  var value2 = parseInt(inputvalue2.value);
  var targetValue2 = parseInt(target_value.value);
  
  if (value2 < targetValue2){
    buttonsubmit2.style.background = 'red' ;
    buttonsubmit2.innerText = value ;
  }
  else if (value2 >= targetValue2){
    buttonsubmit2.style.background = 'green';
    buttonsubmit2.innerText = value ;
  }
  else{
    buttonsubmit2.style.background = '';
    buttonsubmit2.innerText = '2';
  }
  modal.style.display = "none" ;
  return false;
}
```

```css
#inputtarget {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1;
  }
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
}
#modal1 {
  height:70px;
  width:100px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Button and Target Value -->
<div>
<button id="b1" onclick=return checkValue() style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
  <button id="b2" onclick=return checkValue() style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
<input id="inputtarget" type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57';><br>
</div>  

<!-- The Modal Box -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
    <input id=modal1 type="number" ondrop="returnfalse;" onpaste="returnfalse;" 
           onkeypress='return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57'; 
           style=font-size:20px><br>
    <br>
    <button id="submit" onclick="return checkValue()">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: you now have two definitions of `checkValue()` and in the 2nd definition `value` is not defined in `buttonsubmit2.innerText = value ;`. I think I understand what you are trying to do, and one way could be to change the `onclick` property of your submit button in your modal div, in the `btn1.onclick` and `btn2.onclick` functions, and splitting the two `checkValue` functions into a `checkValue1` and `checkValue2`

Comment: Seems like I understand that way you recommend, but by doing that way meaning I have to create individual clickvalue and script for arithmetic operator control as I adding more buttons. Is there a way I can avoid doing that and only remain one arithematic operator control ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your behavior to be the same for every button, so make the button green if the value in the modal box is larger than or equal to the value in the main input field (`inputtarget`), and red if smaller, you could store which button was clicked in a variable by setting that variable in the `onclick` function of every button, and use that to determine which button to change when the submit button of the modal box has been clicked:

```js
// make a variable to store the number of the button:
var btn = 0;
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn1 = document.getElementById('b1');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn1.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    btn=1;
}
var btn2 = document.getElementById('b2');
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    btn=2;
}
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
//Arithematic Operator Control
var target_value = document.getElementById('inputtarget');
function checkValue(){
    var inputvalue = document.getElementById('modal1');
    var buttonsubmit = document.getElementById('b' + btn);
    var value = parseInt(inputvalue.value);
    var targetValue = parseInt(target_value.value);
    
    if (value < targetValue){
        buttonsubmit.style.background = 'red' ;
        buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
    }
    else if (value >= targetValue){
        buttonsubmit.style.background = 'green';
        buttonsubmit.innerText = value ;
    }
    else{
        buttonsubmit.style.background = '';
        buttonsubmit.innerText = '1';
    }
    modal.style.display = "none" ;
    return false;
}
```

```css
    #inputtarget {
      height: 60px;
      width: 100px;
      font-size: 1.5rem;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1;
      }
    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
        display: none; /* Hidden by default */
        position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
        z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
        height: 100%; /* Full height */
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }
    
    /* Modal Content/Box */
    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 240px;
        height: 200px;
    }
    #modal1 {
      height:70px;
      width:100px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<!-- Button and Target Value -->
<div>
    <button id="b1" onclick=return checkValue() style="position:absolute; left:30px; top:100px">1</button>
    <button id="b2" onclick=return checkValue() style="position:absolute; left:80px; top:100px">2</button>
    <input id="inputtarget" type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" 
        onkeypress="return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57;"><br>
</div>  
    
<!-- The Modal Box -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>PLEASE INPUT QUANTITY</p>
        <input id=modal1 type="number" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" 
            onkeypress="return event.charCode>=48 && event.charCode<=57;" 
            style=font-size:20px><br>
        <br>
        <button id="submit" onclick="return checkValue();">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way, if you do not want to use the same arithmetic for each button, you could of course consider to further make the behavior of the `clickValue` function depend on the value of the `btn` variable.